# What do the letter "$\sigma$" and word "algebra" in "$\sigma$-algebra" refer to?

Tags: notation, terminology

I am learning that a $\sigma$-algebra over a set $S$ is a set of subsets of $S$ satisfying certain properties (see e.g. [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sigma-Algebra)).

What do the letter "$\sigma$" and word "algebra" refer to or signify?

(I am most familiar with the use of "$\sigma$" as the symbol for standard deviation, but I'm pretty sure that's not how it's used here. I also know of elementary-school algebra and abstract algebra, but I'm not sure what the connection is here.)

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think $\sigma$ was just an arbitrary symbol chosen to distinguish this kind of algebra from the numerous other types.

Comment: There is an answer on Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74004/what-does-the-%CF%83-in-%CF%83-algebra-stand-for

Comment: @symplectomorphic: Thanks. So $\sigma$ stands for "sum" and is referring in particular to the bit of the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra about Closure under Countable Unions? What about "algebra"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already asked and answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74004/what-does-the-%cf%83-in-%cf%83-algebra-stand-for).

Comment: Algebra because it is a set with one or more operations on it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: My question is different because I also ask about what the "algebra" refers to.

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma$ is a Greek expression derived from the German word 'summe' , back in those days Union of sets was understood as addition of sets!
So $\sigma$ is used to represent the idea of countable Union.
Algebra is all about defining some operations on set and then studying it[defined structure] under the restrictions of those operations.
I hope now it'll [ $\sigma$ -algebra] make sense for you!